# Obtain a ConnectionURI for an Azure VM (ARM)

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

**Q** How can I obtain a `ConnectionURI` for an Azure VM (ARM)?

*Note* In ASM (classic vm) one could simply use the [`Connect-AzureVM.ps1`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-to-an-Azure-85f0782c) to obtain the `ConnectionURI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Azure doesn't assign a dns name for you public IP, so there's only the IP address. So you can get that by making calls to Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress (if you know the name.

if you don't you can go the long route and get the VM network interface and get the publicipaddress from that

Something like:

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVm -Name xxx -ResourceGroup yyy
$nicName = ($vm.NetworkInterfaceIDs[0] -split '/')[-1]
$pip = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName yyy).IpConfigurations.publicipaddress.id
(Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName yyy -Name ($pip -split '/')[-1]).DnsSettings.fqdn
```

something like that, or you could use ipaddress property for the public IP. So not FQDN.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add. What would the easiest route be from a Azure runbook?

Comment: connect to azure from a runbook and use this same code

Answer (score 1):

For ARM VM, the `ConnectionURI` is `<Azure VM Public IP Address>:port`. You could use PowerShell to get your VM public IP. [Public IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm) is a resource VM, you could assign a Public IP to a VM

```
$ip=Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -Name <public IP name>

$ip.IpAddress
```

You also could get Public IP on Azure Portal.

[image]

You could WinRM your VM by using following cmdlets.

```
Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri https://<public-ip-dns-of-the-vm>:port -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck) -Authentication Negotiate
```